# JDBC Connection in Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, stored-procedures, jdbc

What is preferred approach for connection handling in spring, for application having lot of stored procedures? My application involves around 1000 db connections in 1 hour and there are around 150 stored procedures. When the load increases I am getting connection timed out exceptions.

Comment: Use datasource like dbcp or c3p0.

Comment: How are you currently connecting to your database? Do you use a connection pool? Have you tried changing the pool settings to increase the number of connections?

Comment: Currently i am using data source to create connection. I tried increasing the connection pool but it is not working

Comment: Niks could you elaborate i am already using datasource but not about dbcp and c3p0

Comment: I guess what @NiksTyagi meant was that use connection pooling. I added an answer regarding use of c3p0.

Comment: @FaheemSohail correct i mean to say pool.

Comment: @jain626 both are connection pool in which u only need to configure the connection count and whenever u fetch the connection its pool responsibility to provide it.It may possible that single connection is used my so many queries.It will reduce ur db connection count

Comment: thanx Niks and Faheem it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use connection pooling. You may find something useful [here](http://syntx.co/languages-frameworks/java/configuring-c3p0-connection-pooling-with-spring-and-hibernate/) and [here](http://syntx.co/languages-frameworks/configuring-c3p0-connection-pooling-with-jdbc/) if you are using simple jdbc. 
Connection pooling libraries like c3p0 have lots of configurations that allow you to tweak the behavior according to your requirements. If you choose to go with c3p0, you'll find that all configurations possible are well documented [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_properties). Hope it helps!

Comment: Did jbdc template or hibernate have build support for connection pooling or we need to do it using c3p0?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15759592/802061) may help you regarding the question about default support for connection pooling in hibernate. Short answer, it is preferred to use a third party pooling library.

Comment: jain saheb You can use any connection pool with jdbc template and hibernate.You only need to specify