# Spring boot JPA Hibernate default Pool size?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, datasource, max-pool-size

I am building multi-tenancy application with multiple database. I am facing few problems with regard to database pool size (database connection exceeds).

With regard to Spring boot Hiberante JPA, what is the default pool size for datasource? How many connection does hibernate creates by default with given database details in property files?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758647/hibernate-default-connection-pooling, Default seems to be `20`

Comment: Spring Boot uses HikariCP by default (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database), and HikariCP uses 10 min/max connections by default (https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). But of course, it depends on what you might have changed based on your classpath and properties, which you have **not** given.